# Django Model choices based off another model

Tags: python, html, django, forms, model

Sorry if this is confusing, I'm still a bit green with Django.  So basically I have two models and I want a selection from one to have all the choices from another model. So basically:

```
class Show(models.Model):

venue = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices = VENUE NAME)

class Venues(models.Model):
Name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Essentially I want the venue to have a list of the venue names that were input into that model.  Is this possible?

Comment: Use a ForeignKey? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey

Comment: The `__str__()` method of `Venue` should return `self.name`

Answer (score 0):

In your case you should use [many-to-one ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey)

It give you access to `Venues` object from your `Show` object and it simple to add this to your model.

```
class Show(models.Model):
    venue = models.ForeignKey('Venues', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Venues(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

To get your choices you can use:

```
Venues.objects.all()
```

And then the only thing you need is add object or ID to your `Show` object and save.

Choices are good too but not in this case. For example when you need some const and give user choices like this:

```
class Show(models.Model):
    VENUES_CHOICES = (
        (RESTAURANT, 'restaurant'),
        (PUB, 'pub'),
    )

    venues = models.IntegerField(choices=VENUES_CHOICES, default=RESTAURANT)
```

Its great to use it in order status in my opinion.

Comment: Hey!  This works ,however on my Show admin page I get a list of venues but they just say "Venue object" instead of the name.  Any idea here?

Comment: Yes this would work but its not what the OP had asked. Essentially he wants to use a queryset values from the venues table as an option in the shows table.

Comment: Use the ModelChoiceField in a ModelForm class like this: `myFormField = ModelChoiceField(queryset=MyChoices.objects.all())`

Answer (score -1):

add a **str** def like this in the Venues model will do

```
def __str__ (self):
    return self.name
```